# Exceptions in PHP

Tags: php, exception

So i'm trying to learn about exceptions. And i've come accross something people often do , but dont really explain why they do it and how it works. Maybe this is something that speaks for itself but I still dont get it, I apologize if this question might come over as a bad question.

Basically this is the code I'm working with:

```
catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

What is `$e` where is this variable defined. I have an idea.

What i'm thinking is that you're assigning the exception object to the variable `$e` but i'm not sure. Shouldnt it be `catch (Exception = $e)` ?

Comment: There are lots of good examples of code in http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php `$e` is the instance of the `Exception` object being "caught" in this example, you can have multiple `catch` blocks for different classes of Exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works pretty much the same as function parameters:

```
function foo(Bar $bar) { ... }
```

You use a type hint `Bar` followed by the parameter name `$bar`, and that declares the variable.

In the case of `try..catch`, that declaration happens in `catch`:

```
catch (Exception $e) { ... }
```

This uses the type hint `Exception`, which here is used to specify which kinds of exceptions the `catch` is supposed to catch. You can limit the `catch` to specific kinds of exceptions and/or define multiple different `catch` blocks for different kinds of exceptions. The exception itself is then available in the variable `$e`. You can use any arbitrary variable name here, just as for function parameters.

Comment: So basically doing (Exception $e) is assigning the Exception object to the variable $e? So instead of doing Exception->getMessage() you are now able to do $e->getMessage() because you assigned exception to $e?

Comment: I have a another question to follow up on that. Is this required or is it something to make your code cleaner/shorter? And it can be any variable name right? So it could be $error etc

Comment: Yes, exactly. `Exception->...` would be invalid syntax anyway, you need to use a *variable*. In other languages, say, Python, you'd write something like `except FooException as e: ...`, which may be a little clearer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "cleaner/shorter"? As opposed to *what*? If you want to catch an exception, this is the syntax you need to use… And yes, again, the variable name you use is arbitrary and up to you.

Comment: I thought that you didnt need to use a variable, I thought it was just for convinience but i understand now that it's a necesity to assign a variable name to it. That's what i meant with "cleaner / shorter"

Comment: Yes, you need to use *a* variable name. If you're not really interested in ever using `$e`, there's unfortunately no way to omit it in PHP (to compare to Python again, you *can* do `except FooException: ...` without the `as e` there). In PHP you may use the informal convention `catch (Exception $_)` or something to signal that the variable is unused.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, now that i think about it, i have always considered the `Exception $e` to be the input for the `catch()` call.

As far as i know, you are not defining `$e`, as it is already thrown, you are just passing it to the `catch()` block, as you would do with a `function name($input){}`

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

The keyword `Exception` is the type for the parameter `$e`.

In PHP `Exception` is the base exception class that all exceptions derive from so that catch block is a catch-all for all exceptions.

i.e. You might want multiple handlers for different exception types before the catch-all:

```
try {
  someOperation($parameter);
} catch(DatabaseException $e) {
  echo 'Database Exception: ' .$e->getMessage();
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'General Exception: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```